# How to fill in a web form with python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-requests

I am trying to fill this form via a python script:
https://reassurez-moi.fr/devis-assurance-pret-immobilier/60773413ea18bd60703427df9c39cbd2c5c1c8d46fda062f92513e1c266bbfb5

But unfortunately I can't find the code that allows me to select the values from my drop-down lists.

You can notice that in the html we do not have the different options from the drop-down list.

Can you tell me how to make a python script that allows me to fill out this form?

Thank you in advance.

The code below show what I have done so far  but it does not allow me to choose one of the values from my drop-down list

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
web1 = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
web1.get('https://reassurez-moi.fr/simulation-tarifaire-assurance-habitation?homeType=1')
#time.sleep(2)
topics_xpath = '//*[@id="home-comparator-base"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/button'
WebDriverWait(web1,2).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, topics_xpath)))
Rue_Adresse = "Rue de la Paix"
last = web1.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="home-comparator-base"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/form/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/input')
last.send_keys(Rue_Adresse)
ast = web1.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="home-comparator-base"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/button')
ast.click()
```

Comment: why just not use better xpaths and use clicsk for "opening" the dropdown and also for selecting your requested value

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off in this particular website using the Xpath to just highlight all the different input values. You would right click on the element you wish to input information, click inspect then you would right click the element and click on "Copy Xpath". From there however I would use Pyautogui, this would allow you to take over the keyboard. You can then use pyautogui.hotkey('down') to scroll down to the selection you would like. You can also use pyautogui.write('text here') to fill in different text boxes. Pyautogui works well with selenium, you can use the selenium to activate the area you want to work with and manipulate it with pyautogui.

Comment: thank you for your answer but I could not select what I needed to. In fact, pyautogui do not work in the activate area opened with Selenium. It works on my jupyter page not where I need it to work. Do you have any advice? Thanks.